# Alternative to Google's "Material Design?"

Tags: google-material-design

I have really fallen in love with Google's "Material Design" when it comes to building UI for web/mobile/desktop apps. However, it was also the first time that I had encountered such a rich style guide for UI (I come from a web dev background). Are there any other similar style guides, but based on other design principals or aesthetics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are like a million of them... They're called Design Systems, and probably this link will help find the one you love:

https://designsystemsrepo.com/

Comment: or also: https://adele.uxpin.com/

Answer (score 4):

Is this not obvious?

If Google has one... the other players should:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/

Some others are a bit more modest.

https://design.ubuntu.com/

https://developer.gnome.org/hig/

In fact, you can make a search using those terms: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=UI+guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Do you look for a fully equipped framework, or just UI design kits? Probably [Bootstrap Themes](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/) are worth looking into if you need a full framework with different theme options. UI Kits (just the design templates) can be found in abundance via a Google search for *UI Kits* or on commercial sites like [UI8](https://ui8.net/).